# Using torch.argsort in CNN

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

Output of my CNN network is log probabilities. I want to get 10 best indices of the output and further use the indices to get loss.

Hence, I have to use torch.argsort. But using torch.argsort breaks gradients.
Can anyone please help me on how do I proceed?
Thank you very much for the help

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a tutorial site.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `torch.topk`

```
import torch
out = torch.tensor(torch.randn(10, 100), requires_grad=True)
t_v, t_i = torch.topk(out, 10, dim=-1)
print(t_v.requires_grad)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to correct you, argsort does not *break gradients* when you apply its output to mask tensors and this will keep some gradients:

```py
top_indices = torch.argsort(-x)[:10] #get indices of top-10
top_values = x[top_indices]
print(top_values.requires_grad)
```

see https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/differentiable-sorting-and-indices/89304